# Cleaning a SQL schema before using SQL Developer Database copy tool

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database for an application and several environment (development, test and production). I would like to use the option **Database copy** from **SQL Developer** in order to retrieve data from the production and copy them in development. Thus data on both environments will be the same.

With a previous version of the program all was working perfectly. Nevertheless with a new version (SQL Developer 18.2) imposed by our company, I obtain several error with different objects like sequences, existing table, primary key, ...) during the copy.

Thus I would like to use a script for cleaning the objects of the Database before to use the tool in order to see if the problem will be solved. But I don't know how to do that.

I found and updated this script:

```
BEGIN
   FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT object_name, object_type
                     FROM user_objects
                    WHERE object_type IN
                             ('TABLE',
                              'VIEW',
                              'PACKAGE',
                              'PROCEDURE',
                              'FUNCTION',
                              'SEQUENCE',
                              'SYNONYM'
                             ))
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         IF cur_rec.object_type = 'TABLE'
         THEN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    'DROP '
                              || cur_rec.object_type
                              || ' "'
                              || cur_rec.object_name
                              || '" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
         ELSE
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    'DROP '
                              || cur_rec.object_type
                              || ' "'
                              || cur_rec.object_name
                              || '"';
         END IF;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'FAILED: DROP '
                                  || cur_rec.object_type
                                  || ' "'
                                  || cur_rec.object_name
                                  || '"'
                                 );
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Nevertheless this script Cleanup the Schema by DROPPING all objects. I would like to keep the structure and the objects but just empty the  conten.

Could you please help me how to do for cleaning the different object without deleting them and importing again?

Thank in advance for your help.

Sebastien

Comment: I will not be able to solve your problem, but maybe you should provide your error messages in detail. And clarify what you mean by 'clean the objects'? Maybe then someone will be able to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by *"clean"*? What do you mean by *"without deleting"*? We can delete **data** from tables but actual objects can only be dropped.

Comment: I would like just to empty the objects: for instance for the sequences: force the value to 0 - truncate data in all tables (empty values). In any case I would like not to drop the tables and all objects like synonym, index, function, procedure, views. Don't touch to the structure, only empty the values

Comment: It's out of scope of the question but I would rather use `data pump` for this scenario.

Comment: data pump ? is it an option of SQL Developer or a new tool? IF yes where can I find it?

Comment: "Nevertheless with a new version (SQL Developer 18.2) imposed by our company, I obtain several error with different objects like sequences, existing table, primary key, ...) " - please add these errors to your question, then maybe we can help. and Data Pump is a db feature with a complimentary GUI